# Visualforce java script not working on button click

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<script type="text/javascript">
        function msgBox()
        {
            alert("hi");
        }
     </script>
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit" id="pb">

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2" id="pbs">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}" id="fst"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.site}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.type}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.accountNumber}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton onclick="msgbox();" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add you script inside apex:form.. Also Javascript is case sensative so use same name in your `msgBox`.. Thanks to [**@Martin**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/20941/martin) for notice..

And best practice is to add your script end of your HTML code.. So your page DOM should load faster.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit" id="pb">

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2" id="pbs">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}" id="fst"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.site}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.type}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.accountNumber}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton onclick="msgBox();" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function msgBox()
        {
            alert("hi");
        }
     </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hello ratan thanks.I just want to know what is need to write javascript inside form tag i saw code in which its wrote outside form tag and work properly.

Comment: @Bonny ohh my mis.. Basically issue was related to your casesensative.. And yes it will be good practice to use script inside form